Partition function of $N$ distinguishable particles
Suppose there are $N$ distuinguishable particles. Each particle can have energy either $\epsilon_1$ or $\epsilon_2 $. $ n_1$ particles have energy $\epsilon_1 $and $n_2$ particles have $\epsilon_2$ i.e. $N=n_1 + n_2$. What is the partition function? Is it
$$Z= [\exp(-\beta \epsilon_1)+\exp(-\beta \epsilon_2)]^{N}$$
or
$$Z=\exp(-\beta \epsilon_1 n_1)+\exp((-\beta \epsilon_2 n_2)~?$$

It's the first.

Is this for Z_total? If so shouldn't there be a factor of 1/N! In front?

@RudyJD 1/N! is for indistinguishable particles.

@Mr.Wayne, oops thank you I misread your question.

@march I think it should be  $exp(-\epsilon_1 \beta n_1)exp(-\epsilon_2 \beta n_2)$

The partition function for $N$ independent, distinguishable particles is the product of the single-particle partition functions. Expanding out the product in the OP, there is a term for every possible partition of the total energy; i.e., there is a term for each choice of $n_1$ and $n_2$. This is as it should be, because there is a non-zero probability for each one of these configurations. However, if $N$ is very large, the by-far dominant probability is the one for which $n_1=n_2$.
